# MS SQL query hangs diagnostic

Tags: c#, sql-server

There are SQL Query runned at asp .net mvc application. But hang on work server.

1. Run sql in MSSMS on developer PC - OK time < 1 second
2. Run sql in IIS on developer PC - OK
3. Run sql in MSSMS on work PC - OK time < 1 second
4. Run sql in IIS on work PC - IIS stop AppPool by timeout

I add log in code, all hang at SqlDataAdapter(cmd).Fill(...)

I try cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() but hangs too

There are tools (way) for diagnostic why SQL Query hangs at IIS?

C# code

```cs
using(var con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connection"].ConnectionString))
{
    con.Open();

    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(String.Empty, con))
    {
        SqlDataAdapter da;

        cmd.CommandTimeout = 360;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@START", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = start.Date;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@END", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = end.Date.AddDays(1).AddMilliseconds(-1);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@UID", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier).Value = Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey;

        cmd.CommandText = "LONG SQL QUERY";
        //Hang
        //cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        //Hang
        da.Fill(ds.Tables["Data"]);
    }
}
```

P.S. (1) Very intresting

In sql there are filter

```cs
WHERE
    TIN.TransitType = 1
    AND TIN.Time >= @START 
    AND TIN.Time <= @END
```

1. If comment *AND TIN.Time >= @START* query start run good
2. I use ExpressProfiler, and comment *AND TIN.Time >= @START* i see query in profile. If uncommented - no query in ExpressProfiler

Comment: What credentials is the AppPool running under? Does it have the appropriate permissions to query the DB?

Comment: Credentials - ok. All another query from WebApp runned ok.

Comment: You will need to post the code

Comment: Code good work on Developer PC. All another query good runned on Developer and Work PC. Hangs only this query at Work PC IIS but runned at Work PC MSSMS

Comment: Are all your working examples run against the same sql server as the non working one?

Comment: Could be a resource issue. What is the spec of the Work PC? Could also be a network issue? What are the ping times between the PC and the DB?

Comment: Code not runned only Work PC an only in WebApp. IIS kill WebApp by timeout. In MSSMS wuery run < 1 second.

Comment: IIS and SQL runned on one PC

Comment: Is the user different, so the filter criteria for Membership.GetUser() returns something different?data returned by your query something completely different?  The best way to figure this out is to profile the database RPC call using SQL Server Profiler.  Get the RPC call, verify it is the correct parameters, and then  run it yourself in a SQL query window and look at the Actual Execution Plan.

Comment: Have you tried to move the code to stored procedure and running it from there. Then in SQL you can log, if that call ever came through or not.

Comment: Add P.S.(1) problem in TIN.Time >= @FROM